# NDSolve with known tolerance function

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve the differential equation:

```
y'[x]=F[y[x],x]
```

with

`y[0.5]=y0` and `x` is between `0` and `1`, for some (known and numerical) function `F`

I implement this in Mathematica as Follows:

```
NDSolveValue[
 {y'[x] == F[y[x], x], y[0.5] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 1}
```

The results seem accurate for values close to `x=0.5`, but inaccurate for values remote from `x=0.5`

I would like to improve the quality of the solution by imposing `G[y[x],x]=0`. I know the Function `G` (this is how I check my errors). How can I communicate the function `G` to `NDSolve`?

Comment: Please, give us the function F and the value of y0

Comment: F is a compiled function that is obtained numerically. But regardless of the value of F, I would like to know if NDSolve accepts functions like G that "guide" the solver by showing the distance from the true solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is the projection method: [`tutorial/NDSolveProjection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveProjection.html)

The method projects each step onto the invariant manifold indicated by the method option `"Invariants"`.  The interpolation error between the steps does not seem to be controlled as well as the default adaptive step size method in the test example I used, so there seem to be some trade-offs.  One can control the step size with options to improve the result.

Example:

```
Clear[G];
G[y_, x_] := x^3 + y^3 - 2 x y

Clear[F];
With[{cF = Compile @@ {{y, x}, 
     y'[x] /. First@Solve[D[G[x, y[x]], x] == 0, y'[x]] /. {y[x] -> y}}},
 F[y0_?NumericQ, x0_?NumericQ] := cF[y0, x0]
 ]
```

Projection solution:

```
sol = Block[{y0 = y /. FindRoot[G[y, 0.5] == 1, {y, 1}]}, 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == F[y[x], x], y[0.5] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"Projection", "Invariants" -> {G[y[x], x]}}, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/20]
  ];
```

Default solution:

```
sol2 = Block[{y0 = y /. FindRoot[G[y, 1/2] == 1, {y, 1}]}, 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == F[y[x], x], y[0.5] == y0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/20]
  ];
```

Comparison of the error `G[y[x], x] - 1` for the two methods:

```
Plot[Evaluate[G[y[x], x] - 1 /. Join[sol, sol2]], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Epilog -> {Point[
    Transpose[
     Flatten /@ ({y["Grid"], G[y["ValuesOnGrid"], Flatten@y["Grid"]] - 1} /. 
        First@sol)]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see that the steps (black points) have around zero error.  With the default `MaxStepFraction` (`1/10`) the errors are of similar magnitudes, the absolute error of the projection method being slightly greater but the average being slightly less.  I would expect that to depend on `G` and `F` though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extended answer!